# Explicit Feature Maps of the Kernel Trick?

Tags: hilbert-spaces, machine-learning, positive-semidefinite

The [Kernel Trick](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_method) is a technique in machine learning that allows one to write a certain type of bivariate function $$k : \mathcal{X}\times\mathcal{X}\to\mathbb{R}$$ as an inner product on some Hilbert space $\mathcal{V}$.
This is done via what is known as a *feature map* $\varphi: \mathcal{X}\to\mathcal{V}$, which satisfies

$$k(x,x') = \langle \varphi(x), \varphi(x')\rangle_{\mathcal{V}}.$$

This is to say one can represent a (potentially non-linear) kernel via the composition of a

- potentially non-linear feature map $\varphi$, and
- an inner product.

Is there some explicit list of known kernel maps + feature map pairs?
In briefly reviewing materials about the kernel trick, it appears that in machine learning practitioners often do not care about the specifics of $\varphi(x)$.
I do though, as in my application it appears useful to know things like the gradient/Lipschitz constant of $\varphi$.

Comment: The proof of [Mercer's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mercer%27s_theorem) constructs a feature map corresponding to a given kernel, so you could just try applying the steps of the proof to explicit examples.

Comment: I haven't been able to find a list in my brief internet search, but I believe you might be able to find something among the literature on [Reproducing Kernel Hilbert Spaces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reproducing_kernel_Hilbert_space)

Comment: There are some useful properties of feature maps under operations that preserve being psd [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/150964/141174).